# Function composition partial application

Tags: haskell, function-composition, pointfree

Hello can someone explain to me this example from Real World Haskell of function composiiton:

```
data Doc = ToBeDefined deriving (Show) 

(<>) :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc
a <> b = undefined

series :: Char -> Char -> (a -> Doc) -> [a] -> Doc
series open close item = enclose open close
                         . fsep . punctuate (char ',') . map item
                         -- Who does fsep compose with?

enclose :: Char -> Char -> Doc -> Doc
enclose begin end input = char begin <> input <> char <> end
```

I do not understand how who is the right operand of the `. fsep` expression.

```
( . ) [who is here ]  fsep
```

Because from the looks of it close and open are just a characters.Can you compose a function with a data type (in our case a character)?

**P.S** Is it possible to curry the function composition?

so `enclose` accepts 3 parameters: 2 of them are already fixed `open` and `close` and the third one is the result of `fsep`.

Basically you can do `f(x1...xn-1 xn) . g(y1....yn)(k)`  as long as `g(y1...yn)(k)`=xn .

Comment: That's actually the left operand.

Comment: `.` is just like any other operator. `f . g == (.) f g`, and you can define sections like `(f .)` and `(. g)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible to curry the function composition" ?

Comment: I thought that given a function `f` and a function `g`  they both must accept a parameter.In this case its more like `f` accepts 3 parameters ,of which 2 are already fixed and 1 is taken from `g` x - where x is the third parameter.

Comment: (to your question's last sentence:) no, you can do `( f(x1...xn-1) . g(y1...yn) ) (k)` as long as `g(y1...yn)(k) = xn`. ---- also, it probably should have been `enclose begin end input = char begin <> input <> char end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing very exciting going on here. The function you quoted is just

```
series open close item = enclose open close . fsep . punctuate (char ',') . map item
```

with a line break after the `enclose open close` for readability (which changes nothing about how this is parsed). I.e. the operands to the `.` you asked about are `enclose open close` and `fsep`<sup>†</sup>.

Here, `enclose open close` is a partial application of the `enclose` function:

```
enclose :: Char -> Char -> Doc -> Doc
enclose open   ::  Char -> Doc -> Doc
enclose open close   ::    Doc -> Doc
```

thus you're composing a `Doc -> Doc` function before a function that yields a `Doc`.

---

<sup>†</sup>Actually that's technically not quite true: because `.` is *right*-associative, the right operand is actually *everything* to its right, i.e.

```
     (enclose open close) . (fsep . punctuate (char ',') . map item)
```

but due to `f . (g . h) ≡ (f . g) . h` this doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh but i thought that in point free notation you cant have  f(p1,p2,p3) . g(p4,p5,p6)  p7.I mean you can compose functions on the same common parameter but the methods can have other parameters as well ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking there (perhaps you should flesh it out to a separate question), but generally, you can partially apply any number of arguments. If `f :: A -> B -> C` and `g :: D -> E -> B`, then you can write `f a . g d $ e` instead of `f a (g d e)`.

Comment: Thank you that was what i needed to understand !